# Can we have @Column and @OneToOne both annotation for one of the variable?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I have 2 tables

- Table a - id,b_id,name
- Table b - id , name

when I have to make POJO Entity, I wanted to have b_id as a column and as well as foreign key to fetch values from b .

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's no problem. But you have to mark the column read-only either on the b_id column or in the relationship.

Example 1 Column read only:

```
public class A {

    @Column(insertable = false, updateable = false)
    private Integer bId;

    @ManyToOne
    private B b;

}
```

Example 2 Relationship read only:

```
public class A {

    private Integer bId;

    @JoinColumn(name="b_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private B b;

}
```

Comment: When i try to use Example Query like

Example ex = Example.create(a);

Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(A.class).add(ex);


Will it take bId in where clause?

Comment: Yes sure it will

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to just map the foreign key and access the id on the instance of B:

```
A a = em.find(A.class, 1L);
Long bid = a.getB().getBid();
```

This shouldn't cause any performance issues, but for specific cases where it does - there are specific solutions available.

Other approaches are possible, but you will end up having a single piece of data encoded in two places and keeping them in sync will be a constant source of problems and subtle bugs.

Answer (score 0):

use `@JoinColumn` Annotation instead of `@Column` for `Mapped` fields. Read more about `JoinColumn` [at this link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column)